# The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources. "resources": "Magento_Customer::manage"

Tags: api, token, authorize, consumers

magento is sending the next error when calling a GET API.
Does anyone have the solution to the error?

> {
> "message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
> "parameters": {
> "resources": "Magento_Customer::manage"
> },

Comment: You need to use token verification to access this using customer username & password that will generate a token, then you need to use that token in Bearer authentication

Comment: I'm using the bearer token authentication but anyway the error happens

Answer (score 1):

Please check below possible solutions.

Solution 1 :

> Login to Admin >> Stores >> Stores >> Settings >> Configuration >>
> SERVICES >> Magento Web API >> Web API Security >> Allow Anonymous
> Guest Access: Yes

Solution 2 :

> 1. Go into System -> Integrations
> 2. Check the Resource Access set to "All".
> 3. check the Access Token value with the Bearer Token value.
> 4. Open Postman Tool.
> 5. Make a GET request to "https://[mymagentohost].com/rest/V1/xyz
> 6. Set the header "Authorization" to "Bearer TOKEN"
> 7. Make sure that there is no space before or after the token, only one after "Bearer"
> 8. "Content-Type" header set to "application/json".