# Resource access issue for an Integration of custom module

Tags: magento2, module, rest-api, magento2.4.5, integration

I am using Magento 2.4.5 
I created an Integration for my custom module. I am successful in generating the oauth_token & oauth_token_secret. But when I want to see an order using API, I get a 401 error. 
API endpoint:

```
http://dev.magento.com/rest/V1/orders/5
```

API response:

```
"message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
    "parameters": {
        "resources": "Magento_Sales::actions_view"
    },
```

My etc/integration/api.xml & etc/integration/acl.xml is:

```
        <resource name="Magento_Customer::customer" />
        <resource name="Magento_Log::online" />

        <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales" />
        <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales_operation" />
        <resource name="Magento_Sales::sales_order" />
        <resource name="Magento_Sales::actions" />
        <resource name="Magento_Sales::create" />
        <resource name="Magento_Sales::actions_view" />
        <resource name="Magento_Sales::actions_edit" />

        <resource name="Magento_Catalog::catalog" />
        <resource name="Magento_Catalog::catalog_inventory" />
        <resource name="Magento_Catalog::products" />

        <resource name="Magento_Backend::stores" />
        <resource name="Magento_Backend::stores_settings" />
        <resource name="Magento_Config::config" />
        <resource name="Magento_Cms::config_cms" />
        <resource name="Magento_Catalog::config_catalog" />
        <resource name="Magento_CatalogSearch::config_catalog_search" />
        <resource name="Magento_CatalogInventory::cataloginventory" />
        <resource name="Magento_Sales::order_statuses" />

        <resource name="Magento_InventoryApi::inventory" />
        <resource name="Magento_InventoryApi::source" />
        <resource name="Magento_InventoryApi::source_edit" />
        <resource name="Magento_InventoryApi::ship_source_selection" />
        <resource name="Magento_InventoryApi::stock" />
        <resource name="Magento_InventoryApi::stock_edit" />
        <resource name="Magento_InventoryApi::stock_delete" />
        <resource name="Magento_InventorySalesApi::stock" />
        <resource name="Magento_CurrencySymbol::system_currency" />

        <resource name="Magento_Backend::stores_attributes" />
        <resource name="Magento_Catalog::attributes_attributes" />
        <resource name="Magento_Catalog::attributes_attributes" />
        <resource name="Magento_Catalog::sets" />
        <resource name="Magento_Backend::system" />
        <resource name="Magento_AdobeStockAsset::adobe_stock_asset" />
        <resource name="Magento_AdobeStockAsset::actions" />
        <resource name="Magento_AdobeStockAsset::actions_delete" />
        <resource name="Magento_AdobeStockAsset::actions_save" />
        <resource name="Magento_AdobeStockAsset::actions_view" />
        <resource name="Magento_AdobeStockAsset::actions_get" />
    </resources>
</integration>
```

Can anyone help me to get the order data properly?

Comment: Please check mentioned answer of this link. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/363357/the-consumer-isnt-authorized-to-access-resources-resources-magento-custom/363365#363365

Comment: solution 1 is not a possible
solution 2 is ok but I have to create the integration programmatically.

Comment: Don't you have Magento admin access?

Comment: Yes, I have  Magento admin access.