# The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources. Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, api, token

Magento version 2.3.3

Admin token is successfully obtained using the API, however, when trying to fetch any resource using that token, I get this message: "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources."

The user is Administrator and has access to all of the resources.
There's no field labeled "Allow OAuth Access Tokens to be used as standalone Bearer tokens" so that I can enable it.

What else can be done ?

Comment: Can you check the mentioned answer in this link? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/363357/the-consumer-isnt-authorized-to-access-resources-resources-magento-custom/363365#363365

Comment: @JitendraPatel Yes, I checked that, unfortunately it didn't work as well